Zatca invoice - Certificate signature does not match with qr certificate signature value
I have implemented ZATCA using PHP and I am encountering an error while using the compliance API.
Error :

{#1361 ▼ // app/Zatca/API.php:98
  +"type": "ERROR"
  +"code": "CERTIFICATE_SIGNATURE_QRCODE_INVALID"
  +"category": "QRCODE_VALIDATION"
  +"message": "certificate signature does not match with qr certificate signature value "
  +"status": "ERROR"
}


invoice.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionURI>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</ext:ExtensionURI>
            <ext:ExtensionContent>
                <sig:UBLDocumentSignatures xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:sbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2" xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2">
                    <sac:SignatureInformation>
                        <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:1</cbc:ID>
                        <sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>
                        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="signature">
                            <ds:SignedInfo>
                                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11"/>
                                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256"/>
                                <ds:Reference Id="invoiceSignedData" URI="">
                                    <ds:Transforms>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                            <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::ext:UBLExtensions)</ds:XPath>
                                        </ds:Transform>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                            <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:Signature)</ds:XPath>
                                        </ds:Transform>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                            <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:AdditionalDocumentReference[cbc:ID='QR'])</ds:XPath>
                                        </ds:Transform>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11"/>
                                    </ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                    <ds:DigestValue>M5kDKqorytsvMN5A/69Pp4TdqneJ+JUVnYwYARBKX5g=</ds:DigestValue>
                                </ds:Reference>
                                <ds:Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties" URI="#xadesSignedProperties">
                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                    <ds:DigestValue>ODU4ZGZjNjIzNTg0ODFhYWIwMWUyMTNhNWE2MzY3Y2JmNDQ5Y2VjNDU3ZDQ3N2EzODM5M2YyNDU3NGVmNWE4Mw==</ds:DigestValue>
                                </ds:Reference>
                            </ds:SignedInfo>
                            <ds:SignatureValue>MEQCIFrFcmn5b7wSr5Nls6lcdiYx8V8uQ/nD/Y9y0XVt+WA8AiAPBt6tc6qsm7mk2K5BaFWeeKFijvYIR6kWTnD4sIytjw==</ds:SignatureValue>
                            <ds:KeyInfo>
                                <ds:X509Data>
                                    <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                                </ds:X509Data>
                            </ds:KeyInfo>
                            <ds:Object>
                                <xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="signature">
                                    <xades:SignedProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Id="xadesSignedProperties">
                                    <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                        <xades:SigningTime>2024-09-09T13:58:22Z</xades:SigningTime>
                                        <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                            <xades:Cert>
                                                <xades:CertDigest>
                                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                                    <ds:DigestValue>ZTEzMTFhOGJkYTAwNWU4NWIxYmNjZTQwN2E0NDNlYWMyMmQwZTJjYzQxMTRiZTIxNTRkNzEwOGI1MDE5MzM1OA==</ds:DigestValue>
                                                </xades:CertDigest>
                                                <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                    <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=eInvoicing</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>1725890302574</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                                </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                            </xades:Cert>
                                        </xades:SigningCertificate>
                                    </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                </xades:SignedProperties>
                                </xades:QualifyingProperties>
                            </ds:Object>
                        </ds:Signature>
                    </sac:SignatureInformation>
                </sig:UBLDocumentSignatures>
            </ext:ExtensionContent>
        </ext:UBLExtension>
    </ext:UBLExtensions>
    <cbc:ProfileID>reporting:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
    <cbc:ID>EGS1-886431145-1</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:UUID>6f4d20e0-6bfe-4a80-9389-7dabe6620f12</cbc:UUID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2024-09-09</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:IssueTime>09:00:00</cbc:IssueTime>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode name="0211010">388</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
    <cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>ICV</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:UUID>1</cbc:UUID>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>PIH</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">NWZlY2ViNjZmZmM4NmYzOGQ5NTI3ODZjNmQ2OTZjNzljMmRiYzIzOWRkNGU5MWI0NjcyOWQ3M2EyN2ZiNTdlOQ==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>QR</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">AQ1XZXNhbSBBbHphaGlyAg8zMDExMjE5NzE1MDAwMDMDFDIwMjQtMDktMDlUMDY6MDA6MDBaBAYxNjUuNjAFBTI3LjYwBixNNWtES3Fvcnl0c3ZNTjVBLzY5UHA0VGRxbmVKK0pVVm5Zd1lBUkJLWDVnPQdgTUVRQ0lGckZjbW41Yjd3U3I1TmxzNmxjZGlZeDhWOHVRL25EL1k5eTBYVnQrV0E4QWlBUEJ0NnRjNnFzbTdtazJLNUJhRldlZUtGaWp2WUlSNmtXVG5ENHNJeXRqdz09CFgwVjAQBgcqhkjOPQIBBgUrgQQACgNCAAQ/TVJommlMA+TtlsGPBezV61zoUuYp1dGAv/kyQaCHarl7zuHagE8tB1LpxO93J5SfFLJJxKFyfaJvB+Mi12WBCTiurjBFAiAhQZwWQDjrqkKMiGpaOkS5S2pvMpEC3fl97zceWaQTywIhAKq/mte4Aso3FduHer1aFA==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cac:Signature>
      <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:SignatureMethod>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</cbc:SignatureMethod>
    </cac:Signature>
    <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="CRN">454634645645654</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:StreetName>King Fahahd st</cbc:StreetName>
                <cbc:BuildingNumber>0000</cbc:BuildingNumber>
                <cbc:PlotIdentification>0000</cbc:PlotIdentification>
                <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>West</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
                <cbc:CityName>Khobar</cbc:CityName>
                <cbc:PostalZone>31952</cbc:PostalZone>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                <cbc:CompanyID>301121971500003</cbc:CompanyID>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:RegistrationName>Wesam Alzahir</cbc:RegistrationName>
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
        <cac:Party>
         <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
             <cbc:RegistrationName>Wesam Alzahir</cbc:RegistrationName>
          </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">27.60</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">46.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">6.90</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5305">S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5153">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">46.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">2.30</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5305">S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>5.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5153">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">46.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">6.90</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5305">S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5153">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">46.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">2.30</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5305">S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>5.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5153">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">46.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">6.90</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5305">S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5153">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">46.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">2.30</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5305">S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>5.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5153">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">27.60</cbc:TaxAmount>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">138.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">138.00</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">165.60</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID="SAR">0</cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount>
        <cbc:PrepaidAmount currencyID="SAR">0</cbc:PrepaidAmount>
        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="SAR">165.60</cbc:PayableAmount>
    </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">5</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">46.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">9.20</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">55.20</cbc:RoundingAmount>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>TEST NAME 1</cbc:Name>
            <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>5.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">10</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cac:AllowanceCharge>
                <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
                <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>A discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
                <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">2.00</cbc:Amount>
            </cac:AllowanceCharge>
            <cac:AllowanceCharge>
                <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
                <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>A second discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
                <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">2.00</cbc:Amount>
            </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">5</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">46.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">9.20</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">55.20</cbc:RoundingAmount>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>TEST NAME 2</cbc:Name>
            <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>5.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">10</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cac:AllowanceCharge>
                <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
                <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>A discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
                <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">2.00</cbc:Amount>
            </cac:AllowanceCharge>
            <cac:AllowanceCharge>
                <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
                <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>A second discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
                <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">2.00</cbc:Amount>
            </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>3</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">5</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">46.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">9.20</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">55.20</cbc:RoundingAmount>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>TEST NAME 3</cbc:Name>
            <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>5.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">10</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cac:AllowanceCharge>
                <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
                <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>A discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
                <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">2.00</cbc:Amount>
            </cac:AllowanceCharge>
            <cac:AllowanceCharge>
                <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
                <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>A second discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
                <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">2.00</cbc:Amount>
            </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>



I checked the Zatca Techincal Detail Guide. and i think i am having issue in the my tag 9.
How can i cross check the data in my QR with my Invoice XML.
https://zatca.gov.sa/en/E-Invoicing/Introduction/Guidelines/Documents/E-invoicing-Detailed-Technical-Guideline.pdf

